# Plotly Dash- Using For Loop to Generate Multiple Headers Dynamically Inside a Tab

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am creating an application using Plotly/Dash and I am trying to dynamically update the number of inputs that show up in my application, based on the user input from the dropdown. All of this happens inside a tab. However, when I try to do a for loop through the callback to get a fixed number(2) headers, I get this error saying:

> The children property of a component is a list of lists, instead of just a list.

In the layout I defined:

```
[dcc.Input(type= 'number', id='input %i'%i) for i in range(2)]
```

And the corresponding decorator is

```
[app.callback(Output('input %i' % i, 'value'),Input('dropdown-profile-specific', 'value'))(lambda value: None) for i in range(2)]
```

How would I unnest this to get rid of this error. Additionally, how can I make the number of iterations dependent on the length of a list that is provided as the output from another callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'll want to use is a [pattern matching callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/pattern-matching-callbacks) style implementation. Here's a slightly modified version of the first example that I believe is what you are looking for.

In the layout you'll want the dropdown for the number of inputs and a div holder
that holds the the dynamically created inputs:

```
dcc.Dropdown(id='num-inputs', options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in range(1,6)]), # or whatever options you want
html.Div(id='input-container', children=[]),
html.Div(id='inputs-vals') # this is just to show the input values
```

The callback would take the dropdown that supplies the number of inputs as an Input, the Output would be the children of the holder div, and if you want to update the existing children you would add that as a State input parameter (`State('input-container', 'children'))`).

```
@app.callback(
    Output('input-container', 'children'),
    Input('num-inputs', 'value')
)
def add_inputs(num_inputs):
    # Alternatively update existing children
    if num_inputs is None: return ""
    return [dcc.Input(type='number', id={'type':'inputs', 'index':i}) 
           for i in range(num_inputs)
    ]
```

Then the last part is where the pattern matching callback comes into play. We can use the type value we added to the id dict of the inputs to do something for each of the inputs.

```
@app.callback(
    Output('input-vals', 'children'),
    Input({'type': 'inputs', 'index': ALL}, 'value')
)
def use_inputs(values):
    return html.Div([
        html.Div(f'Input {i+1} = {v}') 
        for (i,v) in enumerate(values)
    ])
```